# Failure to override str result for a class object using a decorator

Tags: python

See my answer below; after posting the question I realized what was going on.

---

My attempt to override the string representation of a class using a decorator isn't working. I must be missing something but can't figure out what it is.

```
from functools import wraps

def str_dec(obj):
    @wraps(obj.__str__)
    def __str__(cls):
        return '<desired result>'
    obj.__str__ = __str__
    return obj

@str_dec
class Test():
    pass

assert Test.__str__(Test) == '<desired result>' # success
assert str(Test) == '<desired result>' # failure
```

Obviously the new `Test.__str__` method is being created successfully, but I was expecting it to be called by the `str` function. Instead, `str` is using the default string creation method (for `type` objects).

I can get `str` working using a metaclass, but then the `__str__` method doesn't work! And I would prefer to use a decorator anyway.

```
class str_meta(type):
    def __str__(cls):
        return '<desired result>'

class Test(metaclass = str_meta):
    pass

assert str(Test) == '<desired result>' # success
assert Test.__str__(Test) == '<desired result>' # failure
```

What is going on here? How can I override `__str__` consistently for my class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, the `__str__` method affects the behaviour of class *instances*, not the class *type*.

For your first example, the following does work:

```
assert str(Test()) == '<desired result>'
assert str(Test) == type.__str__(Test)
```

Where the stringification to want to modify is the type, not its instances, you do need a metaclass as in the second example.

I am curious what the use case for that is though. Can see adding a `classmethod` returning a `str` as a named method, but would be surprised by a type that didn't respond to `str()` as per `repr()`.

Comment: [Here is the use case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44011851/dynamically-subclass-an-enum-base-class).

Answer (score 2):

The first example isn't working because the `__str__` method I have added is not going to show up in the MRO for `Test`, only for *instances* of `Test`. Not sure why I didn't see that before.

In short, my decorator as written creates a class method, not a metaclass method.

My final test should be:

```
assert type(Test).__str__(Test) == '<desired result>' # success
```

It turns out that, even doing things correctly, I will not be able to successfully bolt on a new `__str__` method to my class using just a decorator:

```
from functools import wraps

def str_dec(obj):
    @wraps(type(obj).__str__)
    def __str__(cls):
        return '<desired result>'
    # this line causes an error:
    type(obj).__str__ = __str__
    return obj

@str_dec
class Test():
    pass
```

The reason for this is that the type for the class `Test` is in fact `type`, and you cannot override methods of `type`. Instead, you must subclass `type` by creating a metaclass and override *that* metaclass' `__str__` method.

So if I still want to use a decorator, I can, but I need a do-nothing metaclass:

```
class DoNothingMeta(type):
    pass

@str_dec
class Test(metaclass=DoNothingMeta):
    pass

assert Test.__str__(Test) == '<desired result>' # success
assert str(Test) == '<desired result>' # success
```

Now the decorator will work as written because `type(obj)` will evaluate to `type(Test)` and return `DoNothingMeta` instead of `type`, and it is perfectly legal to override dunder methods for a custom metaclass.